Returning a new car to a different dealership in USA?
I purchased a brand new 2024 Honda car with all cash, about 2 weeks ago in Washington State, USA. I live about 2 hours away from the dealer where I purchased the car. Starting two days ago, the car started trembling a bit when I accelerate. I had seen this kind of problem in an old car which had some engine problems, but not did not expect that kind of issue in a new car.
I am hoping this will be easy inspection and fix. But in case I have to return the car and get a new replacement, can I do it at a Honda dealer near me instead of the dealer where I purchased it? I'd prefer to not drive 2 hours or more and risk the car malfunctioning on a freeway. I called one Honda dealer near me and they were not helpful. They said that I could trade it in and get a new car. The trade in would obviously be priced quite low.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Basically, you can take it anywhere, Honda or not, and trade it in. Every dealership in the country will be more than willing to make a deal with you. The problem is, just as you stated, you're going to take a hit on the trade-in value of it, even if it is in perfect shape. This is because, to my knowledge, there's no remorse clause when purchasing a vehicle. Specifically, here in Virginia where I live, the only way there is a remorse clause is if the seller comes to you. In such a case, there is a 72 hour period where the purchaser can nullify a contract. In the case where the purchaser goes to a place, like how most people purchase vehicles, there's nothing. You sign on the dotted line and drive off the lot and you're pretty much stuck with it, or you take a hit on the trade-in. I'm sure it is much the same in most states, including Washington.
Seeing as how you just bought the vehicle brand new, you have other options.
A brand new vehicle comes with two pieces of warranty. First is the regular warranty, which includes things like a "Bumper-to-Bumper" for 36k miles or the powertrain which might be for 60k miles (I'm just throwing numbers out there, your Honda warranty might be different). The second part is an "adjustment period", which when I was selling vehicles, the new car is covered under this for one year. The adjustment period gives you time to get used to the car and see if there is anything you find wrong or problematic. If you do, you can take it back to the dealership and get it fixed.
The other thing to remember is under the warranties, you don't have to take the vehicle back to where you bought it. You can take it to ANY Honda (and most likely Acura as well) dealership and have them fix it for you. The reason for this is, warranty work on your vehicle would be paid by Honda. The dealership does not pay for it.
Bottom line is, it would be my suggestion to you to contact the closest Honda dealership service department and tell them the issues you are having with your brand new vehicle and arrange to have it brought in for warranty service. This is what the new car warranty is all about and you should use it. No vehicle is perfect. Even new ones have problems and that's why they come with a warranty. To give new car owners piece of mind when buying.
Also, there is such a thing as a lemon law, which would allow you to trade the vehicle back in for a different new one. This is a process though, and to my knowledge, isn't executed very often. You just can't waltz into the dealership and say "I want a different car because this one sucks". You have to go through the warranty process and attempt to get it fixed. If, through several attempts to get it fixed the dealership is unable to get the problem(s) fixed, you my be able to apply for it ... but as I said, it's a process and one which doesn't happen very often. From your description, you are no where near the point where you can claim this. You'd have to check the laws in Washington state to know the exactly process for mking it happen.
